# Fastest way to split tensor into list of tensors

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I have a tensor of shape [A,B,C,...] and I wish to create a list of tensors along the 0th dimension. This means that the output should be a 1d list of length A, whose each element is a tensor of shape [B,C,...].

I have seen the [torch.split](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.split.html) function, but the problem is that it returns a 1d tuple of tensors which are of the shape [1,B,C,...] which is not what I want.

For example,

```
>>> minibatch = torch.rand ((4, 2))
    
    tensor([[0.8218, 0.8997],
            [0.4612, 0.9416],
            [0.1481, 0.2389],
            [0.7764, 0.7884]])

>>> torch.split (minibatch, split_size_or_sections=1)

    (tensor([[0.8218, 0.8997]]), 
     tensor([[0.4612, 0.9416]]), 
     tensor([[0.1481, 0.2389]]), 
     tensor([[0.7764, 0.7884]]))
```

What I want as the output:

```
    [tensor([0.8218, 0.8997]), 
     tensor([0.4612, 0.9416]), 
     tensor([0.1481, 0.2389]), 
     tensor([0.7764, 0.7884])]
```

Of course, I can now squeeze each of these tensors across the 0th dimension and get it in the required format, but a quick guide on an easier way to perform this operation would be appreciated.

Comment: You could do it with one extra line: `squeezed_tensors = list(map(torch.squeeze, unsqueezed_tensors))`

Comment: @TrevorPogue will there be efficiency-related issues (as it is quite general and not provided by pytorch) if I use this method? The size of my list can go up to 10^5.

Comment: It should be quite efficient because in CPython, the built-in `map` function is a wrapper for an implementation in C code,  and the `squeeze` is of course still implemented in pytorch

Comment: However, it is possible there may be performance issues from using `list` here, so perhaps you could try just using `map` and keeping the result as an iterable only. Typically you only need to cast an object to list for printing purposes

Comment: `list(x)` will split a tensor `x` on the first dimension